# Actionlink in MVC RC/Beta from codeplex preview 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

In Preview 5, here are the actionlinks that worked fine:

1. ```
               listing is the controller and about is the action
   ```

2.

var values = new RouteValueDictionary();

```
            text and actionname are both strings
```

Html.ActionLink(text, actionName, values);

What would I convert these to get unblocked on the RC release?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand your question but your above example should work just fine with ASP.NET MVC RC.

Answer (score 0):

Nope using this in RC generates this error;

Method not found: 'System.String System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.RouteLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.String, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary)'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I got the latest MVC Futures, and that fixed it.

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24142